# *ngFor not working in dart angular(4)

Tags: angular, dart

I created a super basic project using the latest stagehand to verify this.

The pubspec looks like this:

```
name: angular4_basic
description: A web app that uses AngularDart Components
version: 0.0.1
#homepage: https://www.example.com
#author: Rick Berger <email@example.com>

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0
  angular_components: ^0.6.0

dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1

transformers:
- angular:
    entry_points:
      - web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

Here is main.dart:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

import 'package:angular4_basic/app_component.dart';

void main() {
  bootstrap(AppComponent);
}
```

The app_component.html looks like this:

```
<h1>The Beatles</h1>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let name of names">{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And the app_component.dart looks like this:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [materialDirectives],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent {
  List<String> names = <String>['George', 'Paul', 'Ringo', 'John'];
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
*ngFor="let name of names"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 4, column 3 of AppComponent: ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template
<li *ngFor="let name of names">
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

... followed by a big long stack trace

**Things I Tried**

- Replacing the '*ngFor' with '<ng-template ngFor....></ng-template>' syntax -- that created an unresolved.
- Using the dartdevc compiler

So, what am I missing, here?

Comment: What if you do `*ngFor="let name of names"`, per [the documentation](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/displaying-data#!#showing-a-list-property-with-ngfor)? And what does the root module look like?

Comment: Dangit.  My bad, but no, that doesn't fix it.  By 'root module', you mean the 'main.dart'?  I added it to the original post (and fixed the 'let' kw.)

Comment: What happens when you add NgFor to your list of directives?  IIRC there is no longer any magic COMMON_DIRECTIVES, you must included NgFor, NgIf yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add NgFor or CORE_DIRECTIVES in your directives list next to materialDirectives

Comment: That did it!  Man, I've been crawling all over the web trying to find the answer to this.  You'd think there'd be more notes on this, somewhere.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `let` keyword which means "let `name` be something given by the `ngFor` structural directive, and use this information to build the template below".

What `ngFor` will give you are items from the `names` array.

This is easier to see in the desugared form of structural directives.

```
<ng-template [ngForOf]="names" let-name>
  {{ name }}
</ng-template>
```

Basically, a template is *sort of* a function (it's not, but a nice mental model), and `name` is an argument. You write what the template will look like based on the argument, and `ngFor` supplied arguments for you.

This "argument" is called **context**, and the fact that you didn't specify the name of the context means you've used an **implicit** one. `ngFor` also offers you other "arguments" (other values from the context), such as `index` or `first`.

```
<ng-template [ngForOf]="names" let-name let-i="index">
  {{ i }}. {{ name }}
</ng-template>
```

Here, we've taken a named context `index` and assigned it to a variable `i`. Then we use `i` inside the template. This is similar to having a function with argument's name `i` and then calling it with a variable which is named `index`. Here's a super-simplified version of what happens behind the hood.

```
function render(i) { return i }
for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
  render(index)
}
```

Comment: Adding the 'let' keyword (my bad) doesn't fix it.  See changes above.  Thx.

Comment: It seems like you're missing directives from `common` package. I don't use Dart so I don't know the specifics of how to import it. But the module where you use the component with this template which contains `*ngFor` needs to import the Common Module.

Comment: That is what I thought, too - but in Dart, the 'common' package doesn't seem to be available in angular4 (it doesn't resolve in the IDE, anyway...)  

I think 'common' might have been folded into 'core' in a4?

Trying to force it doesn't fix the issue (and doesn't find 'common')

Comment: There is no `<ng-template>` in Dart.

Comment: Never used Angular with Dart. The original question was lacking `let` so I just tried explaining what it is so the OP wouldn't miss it next time. I assume there's _something_ like it (still named `template`?).